# Single-responsibility and custom data types

Tags: design, c++, single-responsibility

In the past months I've asked for people here on SE and on other sites offer me some constructive criticism regarding my code. There's one thing that kept popping out almost every time and I still don't agree with that recommendation; :P I'd like to discuss it here and maybe things will become clearer to me.

It's regarding the single-responsibility principle (SRP). Basically, I have a data class, `Font`, that not only holds functions for manipulating the data, but also for loading it. I'm told the two should be separate, that loading functions should be placed inside a factory class; I think this is a mis-interpretation of the SRP...

### A Fragment from My Font Class

```
class Font
{
  public:
    bool isLoaded() const;
    void loadFromFile(const std::string& file);
    void loadFromMemory(const void* buffer, std::size_t size);
    void free();

    void some();
    void another();
};
```

### Suggested Design

```
class Font
{
  public:
    void some();
    void another();
};


class FontFactory
{
  public:
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Font> createFromFile(...) = 0;
    virtual std::unique_ptr<Font> createFromMemory(...) = 0;
};
```

The suggested design supposedly follows the SRP, but I disagree — I think it goes too far. The `Font` class is not longer self-sufficient (it is useless without the factory), and `FontFactory` needs to know details about the implementation of the resource, which is probably done through friendship or public getters, which further expose the implementation of `Font`. I think this is rather a case of *fragmented responsibility*.

Here's why I think my approach is better:

- `Font` is self-sufficient — Being self-sufficient, it's easier to understand and maintain. Also, you can use the class without having to include anything else. If, however, you find you need a more complex management of resources (a factory) you can easily do that as well (later I'll talk about my own factory, `ResourceManager<Font>`).
- Follows the standard library — I believe user-defined types should try as much as possible to copy the behavior of the standard types in that respective language. The `std::fstream` is self-sufficient and it provides functions like `open` and `close`. Following the standard library means there's no need to spend effort learning yet another way of doing things. Besides, generally speaking, the C++ standard committee probably knows more about design than anyone here, so if ever in doubt, copy what they do.
- Testability — Something goes wrong, where could the problem be? — Is it the way `Font` handles its data or the way `FontFactory` loaded the data? You don't really know. Having the classes be self-sufficient reduces this problem: you can test `Font` in isolation. If you then have to test the factory and you know `Font` works fine, you'll also know that whenever a problem occurs it must be inside the factory.
- It is context agnostic — (This intersects a bit with my first point.) `Font` does its thing and makes no assumptions about how you'll use it: you can use it any way you like. Forcing the user to use a factory increases coupling between classes.

### I too Have a Factory

**(Because the design of `Font` allows me to.)**

Or rather more of a manager, not merely a factory... `Font` is self-sufficient so the manager doesn't need to know *how* to build one; instead the manager makes sure the same file or buffer isn't loaded into memory more than once. You could say a factory can do the same, but wouldn't that break the SRP? The factory would then not only have to build objects, but also manage them.

```
template<class T>
class ResourceManager
{
  public:
    ResourcePtr<T> acquire(const std::string& file);
    ResourcePtr<T> acquire(const void* buffer, std::size_t size);
};
```

Here's a demonstration of how the manager could be used. Notice that it's used basically exactly as a factory would.

```
void test(ResourceManager<Font>* rm)
{
    // The same file isn't loaded twice into memory.
    // I can still have as many Fonts using that file as I want, though.
    ResourcePtr<Font> font1 = rm->acquire("fonts/arial.ttf");
    ResourcePtr<Font> font2 = rm->acquire("fonts/arial.ttf");

    // Print something with the two fonts...
}
```

### Bottom Line...

(It'd like to put a tl;dr here, but I can't think of one. :\ )
Well, there you have it, I've made my case as best as I could. Please post any counter-arguments you have and also any advantages that you think the suggested design has over my own design. Basically, try to show me that I'm wrong. :)

Comment: Reminds me of Martin Fowler's [ActiveRecord](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/activeRecord.html) vs [DataMapper](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html).

Comment: Provide convenience (your current design) in the outermost, user-facing interface. Use SRP internally so that it will ease your future implementation changes. I can think of Font loader embellishments that skips italic and bold; that only loads the Unicode BMP, etc.

Comment: [Keynote: How to design a good API and why it matters - Joshua Block](http://lcsd05.cs.tamu.edu/slides/keynote.pdf)

Comment: @rwong I know of that presentation, I had a bookmark to it ([video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aAb7hSCtvGw)). :) But I don't understand what you're saying in your other comment...

Comment: @Paul: your outermost `Font::loadFromFile` can be a simple one-liner call to `FontFileLoader::Initialize`. You can keep your `FontFileLoader implements IFontLoader` private - until users complain that they need more power. That said, keep-it-simple; those are just design choices you can choose from.

Comment: @rwong Isn't it already a one liner? You only need one line, whether you load a Font directly or through the ResourceManager. And what stops me from reimplementing the RM if users complain?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with that code in my opinion, it does what you need it to in a sensible and reasonably easy to maintain manner.

*However*, the problem that you have with this code is that if you want it to do anything else *you're going to have to change it all*.

The point of the SRP is that if you have a single component 'CompA' that does algorithm A() and you need to change algorithm A() you shouldn't have to change 'CompB' as well.

My C++ skills are too rusty to suggest a decent scenario where you will need to change your font management solution, but the usual case I make is the idea of sliding in a caching layer. Ideally you don't want the thing that loads stuff to know about where it comes from, nor should the thing being loaded care where it comes from, because then making changes is simpler. It's all about maintainability.

One example might be you loading your font from a third source (say a character sprite image). In order to achieve this you will need to change your loader (to call the third method if the first two fail) and the Font class itself to implement this third call. Ideally, you'd just make another factory (SpriteFontFactory, or whatever), implement the same loadFont(...) method and stick it in a list of factories somewhere that can be used to load the font.

Comment: Ah, I see: if I add one more way to load a font, I'll need to add one more acquire function to the manager and one more load function to the resource. Indeed, that's one disadvantage. Depending on what this new source might be, however, you'll probably have to handle the data differently (TTFs are one thing, font sprites are another), so you can't really predict how flexible a certain design is going to be. I do see your point, though.

Comment: Yeah, like I said, my C++ skills are pretty rusty so I struggled to come up with a viable demonstration of the issue, I agree about the flexibility thing. It really depends what you're going for with your code, like I said, I think your original code is perfectly reasonably solution to the problem.

Comment: Great question and great answer, and the best thing is that multiple developers can learn from it. This is why I love hanging out here :).  Oh and so my comment isn't completely redundant, SRP can be a little bit tricky because you do have to have to ask yourself 'what if', which can seem counter to: 'premature optimisation is the root of all evil' or 'YAGNI' philosophies. There's never a black and white answer!

Answer (score 0):

One thing that bugs me about your class is that you have `loadFromMemory` and `loadFromFile` methods.  Ideally, you should have only `loadFromMemory` method; a font should not care how the data in memory came to be.  Another thing is that you should use constructor/destructor
instead of load and `free` methods.  Thus, `loadFromMemory` would become `Font(const void *buf, int len)` and `free()` would become `~Font()`.

Comment: The load functions are accessible from two constructors, and free is called in the destructor -- I just didn't show that here. I find it convenient to be able to load the font directly from a file, instead of first opening the file, writing the data to a buffer and then passing that to Font. Sometimes I also need to load from a buffer, though, which is why I have both methods.